# JSON Parser Golang

Tags: golang

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно дописать JSON парсер, чтоб когда строки разархивировались не падал код? То есть при компиляции код встречает текст, а не архив, сразу падает (в поле data в перемешку текст и архив). Надо написать чтоб пропускал строку с текстом. Логика такая: Читается data из базы, делается `json.Unmashal` или `json.NewDecoder` (не могу понять что использовать), если `Unmarshall` не сработал - будет err, тогда если есть err то надо разархивировать и снова делать `Unmarshall`.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "compress/zlib"
    "bytes"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "name:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:port)/database")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT data FROM user_stats ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 10`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var data []byte

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        r, err := zlib.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicf("Cannot read archive %v", err);
        }
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
        r.Close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Задаём структуру нашего JSON
type UserStatsData struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field_1"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2"`
}
userStatsData := UserStatsData{}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &userStatsData)
if err != nil {
    // Здесь распаковываете data в []byte, и снова вызываете json.Unmarshal()
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался.